# Error: The apk has permissions that require a privacy policy set for the app, e.g: android.permission.CAMERA

Tags: android, google-play, android-permission

Estou tentando publicar um APP na minha lojas de testes, o build funciona normal, mas quando tento publicar na loja aparece o erro descrito acima.

Pelo que tenho visto é necessário informar no `Google Play Console` uma politica de privacidade porque no meu caso estou tentando utilizar o recurso da câmera, segundo esse artigo: [How to fix Google Play Developer policy violation: Action Required *Policy issue*](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/)

> O Google Play exige que os desenvolvedores forneçam uma política de
>   privacidade válida quando o aplicativo solicitar ou manipular
>   informações confidenciais de usuários ou dispositivos. Seu aplicativo
>   solicita permissões confidenciais (por exemplo, câmera, microfone,
>   contas, contatos ou telefone ) ou dados do usuário , mas não inclui
>   uma política de privacidade válida.

No artigo diz para seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Vá para o seu Console do desenvolvedor do Google Play.
2. Selecione um aplicativo.
3. Selecione a listagem de lojas.
4. Em `Política de Privacidade`, insira o URL no qual você tem a
   política de privacidade hospedada on-line.
5. Selecione Salvar rascunho (novos aplicativos) ou Enviar atualização
   (aplicativos existentes). ”

Eu não encontrei dentro do console a parte que diz: `Selecione a listagem de lojas`, onde eu poderia encontra-lá?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após realizar a seleção do aplicativo:

1. Abra o menu lateral tem uma opção chamada ***Presença na Loja***.
2. Clique em Detalhes do App.
3. No final da página de Detalhes do App você encontrará o local para
   inserir a URL da sua politica de privacidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou. Pqp tava na minha cara e não via rs!

Comment: Essa interface de manuteção dos apps é bem complicada msm. Valeu